# A bijection between the two sets in Ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $\mathcal{H}=Hom\Big( \mathbb{Q}(i)[y],\mathbb{Q}(i) \Big)$ be the set of all homomorphisms, such that, the restriction of the homomorphism on $\mathbb{Q}$ is identity. Let $A=\{ 1,-1,i,-i  \}$. Then find a bijection between $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i)\times A.$

I have transferred this problem to the quotients as $\mathbb{Q}(i)\cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i)[y]\cong \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2+1). $ Now I have to see how all the homomorphisms look like between $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $ \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2+1) $. For this I tried to apply the  [Universal Property of Quotient Ring](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Universal_Property_of_Quotient_Ring). So basically, I have to find all the homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1)$ such that the ideal $(x^2+1)$ is contained in the Kernel of the homomorphism. But I was unable to go after this. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Yeah, i got it. I made the correction. Basically the set $A$ is $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$. Thanks.

Comment: I believe your correction is still not correct. You want $(a,b) = (0 , \pm 1)$ or $(a,b) = (\pm 1, 0)$ at least when you restrict yourselves to $a, b \in \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Sorry, again. I typed it correctly.

Comment: I still read $(a,b) = (\pm i, 0)$...

Comment: This was the typos in my problem sheet that I did not  noticed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First show that a homomorphism $f : \mathbf{Q}(i)[y] \to \mathbf{Q}(i)$ that fixes $\mathbf{Q}$ is determined exactly by what $f(y)$ and $f(i)$ are. Since $y$ has no relations in $\mathbf{Q}(i)[y]$, we can have $f(y)$ be any element of $\mathbf{Q}(i)$. Since $i^4 = 1$ we must have $f(i)^4 = f(i^4) = f(1) = 1$. Thus $f(i) \in A$. Now show that given any $\omega \in \mathbf{Q}(i)$ and $j \in A$ we can construct a (unique) homomorphism $f : \mathbf{Q}(i)[y] \to \mathbf{Q}(i)$ with $f(y) = \omega$ and $f(i) = j$.

For example with $f(y) = 2$ and $f(i) = -1$ we have
$$ f\Big( (1 + i) + 3y + (2 - i)y^2 \Big) = (1 + (-1)) + 3(2) + (2 - (-1))(2)^2 = 18. $$

Comment: I did not understand. Can you please elaborate it please?

Comment: @XYZABC I've added some more details.

Comment: Maybe it's silly question, but how do I show that given any $\omega \in \mathbf{Q}(i)$  and $j\in A$ we can construct a (unique) homomorphism $  f : \mathbf{Q}(i)[y] \to \mathbf{Q}(i)$ with $f(y)=\omega$ and $f(i)=j$.

Comment: @XYZABC Look at the example. Can you see what would happen if we replaced $f(y) = 2$ and $f(i) = -1$ with $f(y) = \omega$ and $f(i) = j$?

Comment: It will give, $1+j+3\omega+(2-j)\omega^2$. But how is it useful? I am not getting what is the use of  "18" that you got in your example.

Comment: @XYZABC Now what would $$ f \left( \sum_{n = 0}^N (a_n + b_n i) y^n \right) $$  be?

Comment: It will be $$  \sum_{n = 0}^N (a_n + b_n j) \omega^n. $$